# Hive Reducer completing all but last task

Tags: hadoop, hive

Our Hadoop instance is getting progressively slower. Our jobs now seem to always get to

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED    450        450        0        0       0       0
 Reducer 2 .....      RUNNING    514        513        1        0       0       0
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 VERTICES: 01/02  [=========================>>-] 99%   ELAPSED TIME: 24659.48 s 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and then hangs there for HOURS?!?

Why doesn't that last job just fail, and then restart? Is there a setting I can set so that tasks that take 10x longer than the longest running job after the first 200 get killed and restarted?

I am not an admin, and our actual admin are all working on the GCP migration. My monthly job went from taking one day to two, and then last month five days. I don't want to think about how long this month's processing is going to take.

Help. please.